# Organise custom classes

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to learn the basics of [Slim 3](http://www.slimframework.com/) and I have difficulties trying  to figure out the proper way to organise my custom code, esp. custom classes. For instance, I want to create a [custom error handler](https://akrabat.com/logging-errors-in-slim-3/):

```
<?php
namespace App\Handlers;
// [...]
final class Error extends \Slim\Handlers\Error
{
    // [...]
}
```

... but the documentation I've checked hasn't revealed under which path to save the class definition or how to configure the framework so it can be found in my `index.php` entry point:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
// [...]
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return new App\Handlers\Error($c['Logger']);
};
```

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Handlers\Error' not found

I'd appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is not related to the framework at all.

Slim doesn't tell you where to keep your custom code because it's a matter of your free choice.

Your error:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Handlers\Error' not found

is not generated by Slim, but PHP itself. You need to add an autoloader for your code to let PHP know where to find appropriate classes.

I can see that you utilize Composer, therefore it's the best option to [configure composer.json to create autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) for your code.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with microframeworks is that you never know whether a given feature is provided by the tool. I also wasn't aware that you could/should use Composer to auto-load external code.